# Could crows be used to carry messages or does that sound dumb?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, communication

First time posting on this site. Up until today I actually thought stackexchange was actually a programming forum thing, heh.

Anyway, I'm writing a medieval, low tech fantasy novel and I'm wondering if you think the training of crows to carry messages makes sense? I know plenty of fantasy uses pigeons and ravens, but I'm set on using crows as it ties in with some parts of my world's religion.

So, yeah? Sound feasible or does it just make you roll your eyes?

Comment: Should be feasible.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Worldbuilding! I think this question has been asked before. Maybe you will find your answer(s) here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/42/are-ravens-a-genuinely-realistic-way-of-carrying-messages

Comment: @wetcircuit You should flag as duplicate.

Comment: Can't it be both, feasible and a bit dumb because so cliché since game of thrones became that popular?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2549 ( IP over Avian Carriers with Quality of Service)

Answer (score 2):

Using crows would have the same plausibility of using ravens (or owls, or some other bird).

AFAIK pigeons are the only ones actually used in practice because their natural instinct makes them return to their nest even after being taken afar. Other birds have similar instincts (e.g.: swallows) but neither crows nor ravens share it (AFAIK).